# Sybase IQ - Pull the last 30 days of data where the most recent date is not today

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

**Objective**: Pull the last 30 days of data from a table that has a variable end date

**Background**: I have a table that contains purchase information but this table is only updated every two weeks therefore there's a lag in the data. Some day it can be 14 days behind and others 13 or 15 days behind.

My table contains a DATE_KEY column which joins to the DATE_DIM table on this key which is where I pull my date field from. I would use GETDATE or CURRENT_DATE but this is not appropriate in my case due to the lag.

I am using Sybase IQ and I believe I can't use a select statements in the where clause to compare dates, I got the following error:

```
Feature, scalar value subquery (at line 63) outside of a top level SELECT list, is not supported.
```

This is what I was trying to do

```
WHERE
        TIME.[DAY] >= DATEADD(dd,-30,(  SELECT 
                                        MAX([TIME1].[DAY]) 
                                        FROM DB.DATE_DIM TIME1 
                                        JOIN DB.PURCHASES PURC 
                                        ON TIME1.KEY = PURC.KEY))
```

How can I pull the most recent 30 days of data given the constraints above?

Comment: And why doesn't your code work?

Comment: It could be helpful to see more of your query. From what I can see here, my intuition tells me a 'JOIN' would be more appropriate than a 'WHERE' (yes ... all equivalencies aside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Sybase IQ documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1530/doc/html/san1278452853927.html), you can use a comparison to a subquery, hence you could add a join to the `DATE_DIM` to the main FROM clause, and then compare that to a subquery similar to yours, just with the `DATEADD` moved into it. In the following code, I assume the alias for `DATE_DIM` in the main FROM clause is `TIME0`.

```
WHERE
     TIME0.[DAY] >= (SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-30, MAX([TIME1].[DAY]))
                     FROM DB.DATE_DIM TIME1 
                     JOIN DB.PURCHASES PURC 
                     ON TIME1.KEY = PURC.KEY
                    )
```